# What are the differences between iframe and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I was doing an innerHTML on a div element. MY lead comes and tells me that innerHTML and iFrame are both the same. Now this one was something new. I always thought InnerHTML to be different from iFrame.

> [My lead]: "The issue is because he is trying to use innerHTML which
>   in turn is called as IFRAME for a browser"

I wanted to know the differences between an iFrame and innerHTML. Are they both essentially similar in nature? I looked but couldn't find much.

Thanks

Comment: completely wrong..you should put a case against a person / book who tought you this..Read [Professional-JavaScript](http://www.amazon.in/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691).

Comment: [MDN innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.innerHTML) ... [MDN iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553879/iframe-vs-innerhtml-for-a-modal-dialog-which-is-better

Comment: @Pilot: Something tells me there's a misunderstanding between the two. We have no context to go by here.

Comment: Added the context. I was absolutely bummed when I read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a communication error--e.g., if your lead means that the `innerHTML` of that div is just going to show an iframe as its innerHTML (or otherwise, it would sound like you need a new lead). `innerHTML` grabs the HTML code as a string inside of the selected element. An iframe is an element used for transcluding content (usually from other sites or other pages on your own site). Apples and oranges...

Answer (score 2):

They're very different.  An iframe tells the browser to load a different URL in the iframe, and it will often have it's own scrolls.  But a div can be made to look and work like an iframe by setting 
    overflow: auto 
- in the style.  Maybe that's what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Innerhtml is a way to access the contained html of an html element. An iframe is an element that let's you display content from a different web page than the one you're currently on.

Comment: A parent element doesn't contain HTML. The `.innerHTML` property getter has to generate HTML on the fly by analyzing the DOM nodes of the descendants.

Answer (score 1):

`iframe` is an HTML tag used for displaying another website or page on your page, `innerHTML` is used in Javascript to change the content of an element on your webpage.
 **They are completely different.**